# Can't create own cube on Saiku

Tags: jdbc, configuration, mdx, saiku

I would like to create cube with connection to MS SQL Server 2012. I downloaded Saiku with Foodmart DB which runs successfully. Currently, I have edited schema file to be my own data. Also, I changed to connection in saiku-datasource to be:

```
type=OLAP name=xmla driver=org.olap4j.driver.xmla.XmlaOlap4jDriver
location=jdbc:xmla:Server=http://localhost/olap/msmdpump.dll
```

After restarting the saiku, nothing is shown in the drop-down list of the cube. I am not sure if it caused from wrong connection string. But I have tested this configuration with SQL Server Studio, and it works properly.

By the way, I am not sure if I have to edit file in saiku-repository or not. I think it is the MDX or query file, but I am not sure. I don't know if I also have to edit this file or not as it is not mentioned in the documentation. So far, the file is still the same as original one. Could this also be the reason no list is displayed in my cube?

Could anyone help me figure this out, please ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It seems you should add security parameters in this file
Try this:
security.enabled=true security.type=passthrough

And if its problem related to security and roles refer -
http://ask.analytical-labs.com/questions/3071/saiku-and-ssas-security-roles

It might be the 2nd case problem related to ssas 2000 and ssas 2005 difference then refer-http://ask.analytical-labs.com/questions/2388/ssas-2000-with-saiku

And please provide the server log if any error is thrown in the back.

Answer (score 0):

Was there any error ? You can check out the saiku.log files for errors.
Otherwise Try this,

type=OLAP 
name=xmla 
driver=org.olap4j.driver.xmla.XmlaOlap4jDriver 
location=jdbc:xmla:Server=http://localhost/olap/msmdpump.dll

Just use the configurations in separate lines of their own.